# Meg having cake in the bathtub reference

Tags: reference, family-guy

In the "Emmy" episode of Family Guy there is a scene in which Meg is eating cake in the bathtub:

[image]

She says,

> You've inspired me to nakedly eat this cake in a weird place.

What is this a reference to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice Meg's short hair and tattoo? That's [Lena Dunham](https://charlie-p-2ac84d7056ca7f9d.s3.amazonaws.com/clips/thumbnails/000/022/585/medium/1HY9U68_183_lt.jpg). They're parodying Hannah from [Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girls_(TV_series)), who ate a cupcake in a tub in the very first episode. She was talking to Marnie at the time, though, and Peter's clothes look like something [Jessa](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/07/31/article-2382213-1B16462D000005DC-202_306x570.jpg) would wear, so they could be from another episode. Dunham's hair was longer in season one, but Hannah eating cake and tub scenes with her friends were kind of running themes in *Girls*. Here's a pic from that first episode:

[image]

Dunham also ate cake naked in a bathroom stall in a [*Girls* parody for the Emmys once](https://www.about-face.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Lena-Dunham-nude-with-cake.jpg) (**NSFW**).